# What would the best approach be to dynamically load options for a select tag?

Tags: laravel, rest, vue.js

I am trying to decide on the best solution to loading form options dynamically with a restful api approach in mind. Im using laravel for the back end and Vue components to handle the frontend that live inside blade templates where necessary.

Currently my controllers all return a blade view that contains Vue components which handles all the front end stuff such as forms etc. So I am just wondering what the best approach would be to loading options for a select. I've thought of a few ways:

1. Pass the options necessary to the view and define them as props on the component.
2. Keep it as is and when the vue component loads go and fetch options via an api endpoint.

The problem with approach 1 is that my components are tightly coupled to the view it belongs to and I have to make sure in every controller that returns a view where a component requires some options i would have to pass down a potentially random set of collections to the view for example a collection of companies and roles could be passed down to the user edit view and assigned as props which can bloat the controller and cause confusion where it's not immediately clear what those collections are intended for unless you go to the component that's using them.

With approach 2 I can have a generic select component that takes a url as a prop and can easily reuse it everywhere with v-model. The problem with this approach is it doesn't feel right to have an entire route dedicated to return a different structure of an existing route for example:

`/api/company/1/users` -> returns array of entire objects and relationships

`/api/company/1/users/options` -> returns array of only id and name

The best solution I could think of is to go with **option 2** and use the original route but with a parameter to determine the response structure:

`/api/company/1/users?options=true` -> controller checks for options and returns option version of users instead of all attributes+relationships.

So is there an ideal approach to handling this? Both approaches work but I'm hoping to get some advice on the best approach or there might be another way I haven't thought of.

Thanks.